# How can I check the operating system from website viewers?

Tags: python, flask, operating-system

I need to check the operating system from website viewers using flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not accurately determine the exact OS, but you can get the [`User-Agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) provided by the browser. Flask will parse this into an object in [`request.user_agent`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/utils/#module-werkzeug.useragents).

```
from flask import request

request.headers.get('User-Agent')
```